# How do you prevent section header in a UICollectionView from disappearing when dynamically resizing cells on prepare

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that loads images on `willDisplay`, and based on the image dimensions, updates the cell's image height constraint and calls `performBatchUpdates` on the ViewController. This however is causing my section header to slide up and disappear. What are some possible strategies to circumvent this from happening?

Note: The reason why I use `performBatchUpdates` is to preserve the animation when the cell expands for some other reason (label height increase.)

[image: Gif of UX]

Comment: For the gif you included, it looks like your tableView style is `plain`, is that correct? If so, you could try to change it to `grouped` but then the whole style of the tableView will be a little different

Comment: This is a collectionview

Comment: Ups, sorry :S Did not read correctly